# How to save to database through xml

Tags: ios4

I am calling a server side api which returns me the DB rows in xml format. I have parsed it. Then I edited the xml in iphone. Now I want to save the xml back to server with the changes. Then server side php script will parse the xml to save the changes to reflect in the database. My question is when I was calling the api , it was returning xml response. But how can I feed the xml to the api. I guess by constructing URL. If so what should I write HTTP request header? I think I have to use post method. I dont want to use SOAP, I want to use REST. Can anyone suggest any sample about this topic?
Thanks 
Rupaanjaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a request like this...

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:your-url];
[request setValue:set-appropriate-value forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:set-value forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:NSData-object-holding-data-you-intend-to-post-on-server];
```